# Apache two redirect conditions in one redirect rule

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, apache-ds

example.com , now what I need is request comes to example.com and www.example.com redirect to https://www.example.com,

This is my apache redirect code

```
    RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$  [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

If I add `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$  [NC]`

browser says too many redirects or redirect loop, how to solve this, I have sub domain configuration also so the condition not to affect subdomain redirects...

Answer (score 1):

You [don't need mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect) for this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost >
```

But if you really want to use mod_rewrite

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost >
```

Comment: see, the thing is i have some sub domain also , so I cant make     Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/" , I need www.example.com and exmaple.com to https://www.example.com

Comment: Just change the redirect targets and/or add the subdomain the ServerAlias. Or create a new vhost for the subdomain and redirect it appropriately.

Comment: How to do that one?

Comment: A friendly search engine (even the one in the top right) and the documentation are your friend, I've stopped doing  Reading Documentation As A Service.